# python: threading & curses

Tags: python, консоль, логирование, curses

Пытаюсь сделать консольный интерфейс к python скрипту, который состоит из потоков.

Каждый поток имеет свой logger. И постоянно пишет свой лог файл.

Кондуктор, главный поток, должен уметь переключать stdout с одного потока на другой, и общую стату, где-нибудь вверху светить, "сколько всего поток", контрольку, свитчер stop/start для каждого из потоков, кнопку `q` - забиндить на `quit`, и т.д.

При этом logger-ы должны печатать логи непрерывно, что бы их можно было почитать. Но интерфейс удобнее будет если лог каждого потока будет выводится отдельно от остальных, иначе нечитабильная каша получается.

Как это сделать просто ?

```
stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.addstr(0, 10, line_of_log)
```

`curses` кладёт линию на экран так, что если строчка лога будет добавляться снизу/сверху, то шифт всего текста - это перерисовка всего экрана что-ли?

Похожая конструкция, которую я хочу реализовать есть в [tor-arm](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en), его сейчас и читаю.

Кроме `curses` можно ли как-то такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы каждый лог в отдельном `curses` окошке выводился, достаточно  [`logging.Handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) добавить к каждому `logger` (каждому свой, если надо). Вот [пример `Handler`, который выводит на экран, используя `curses`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28102809/4279).